# How correct is this code to compute truncated lognormal distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, normal-distribution

I need to generate truncated lognormal distribution with minimum, maximum and size values of 0.0005, 0.01 and 1000 respectively. I have come up with the following code but not sure if it's correct and valid.

```
mu = 0  # Mean of the lognormal distribution
sigma = 1  # Standard deviation of the lognormal distribution
min_val = 0.001  # Minimum value
max_val = 0.01  # Maximum value
size = 1000  # Number of samples

# Define the truncation limits in the standard normal space
a = (np.log(min_val) - mu) / sigma
b = (np.log(max_val) - mu) / sigma

# Generate the truncated lognormal distribution
truncated_samples = truncnorm.rvs(a=a, b=b, loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=size)

# Transform the samples back to the original scale
truncated_samples = np.exp(truncated_samples)
```

Comment: Defining how 'correct' some code is is a vague question.

The efficiency of your code depends on how the truncnorm.rvs() function generates the samples. The specific details of its time complexity are not provided in the docs.

If we assume that generating a single sample has a time complexity of O(1), then generating size number of samples will have a time complexity of O(size). Therefore, the overall time complexity of this code is O(size).

This is kind of speculative tought. It's really hard to tell without looking at the source code of the library implementing truncnorm.rvs().

Comment: Also, this is more a math question than a programming question.

Comment: `minimum, maximum and size values of 0.0005, 0.01 and 1000 respectively` This code defines the minimum as 0.001, so that part is incorrect.